# CiviDiscount - what is the correct URL for contribution pages

Tags: contribution-page, cividiscount

I am working with CiviDiscount 3.1, CiviCRM 4.6.9 and latest Drupal. I have set up a membership discount and would like to use it on contribution pages.

According to [documentation](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviDiscount+Extension+Module), for Event Pages the URL is supposed to be like this: civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=XXX&discountCode=YYYY

Can anyone tell me how the url is supposed to look for (membership) contribution pages? civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1&discountCode=YYYY does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation page was outdated. The correct format for event pages is

```
civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=XXX&discountcode=YYYY
```

and

```
civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=XXX&discountcode=YYYY
```

for contribution pages

Comment: Only one capital but such a difference ^^